# Can't specify path to training images which I have uploaded in my google drive in my google colaboratory for deeplearning

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, google-colaboratory

this is the directory tree or structure of my drive when I run the following commands in my colab

```
!ls
```

gdrive sample_data

```
!ls  gdrive/'My Drive'/'Colab Notebooks'
```

dogs-vs-cats  dogvscat.ipynb  Untitled0.ipynb

I am working on dogvscat.ipynb file and data(images of cats and dogs) that are inside train ,valid and test directory of dogs-vs-cats from above code we can see that both file and dogs-vs-cats folder are in same directory.

```
#I specified the paths as string
train_path='./dogs-vs-cats/train'
valid_path='./dogs-vs-cats/valid/'
test_path='./dogs-vs-cats/test/'
```

and ran the flowing code I have imported keras code I have imported all the neccessary modules
inside each train ,valid and test folder I have two subfolders named cats and dogs with contain about
500pics which is a very small number since I am just a beginner.The main problem is that when a run
below code

```
train_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=train_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
valid_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=valid_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10)
test_batches = ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=tf.keras.applications.vgg16.preprocess_input) \
    .flow_from_directory(directory=test_path, target_size=(224,224), classes=['cat', 'dog'], batch_size=10, shuffle=False)
```

I get this output

```
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.
Found 0 images belonging to 2 classes.
```

so the problem is I don't know how to specify the path that will make this code work.
So please kindly help
As additional informational below is the list of all the modules that I have imported

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Activation,Dense,Flatten,BatchNormalization,Conv2D,MaxPool2D
from tensorflow.keras.metrics import categorical_crossentropy
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import itertools
import os
import shutil
import random
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
%matplotlib inline 
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

this is link to the copy of file in github
https://github.com/shahchhatru/Bikramrepository/blob/master/dogvscat.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

A folder by the name 'Colab Notebooks' is by default created in your google drive. Move your dogs-vs-cats folder containing train, valid and test folders along with your python notebook into the 'Colab Notebooks' folder. Then the path to your train, valid, and test folders will be:

```
train_path='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dogs-vs-cats/train'
valid_path='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dogs-vs-cats/valid/'
test_path='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/dogs-vs-cats/test/'
```

Run the rest of the code as it is. I hope this works.